# GC Lagging app when scrolling my custom component

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I had to create a custom component (I could not use gridview or dataTable), which is a table with 6 columns and X rows (no images). The image below shows it working:

[image: Screenshot]

The problem occurs when I scroll up or down on that table. Sometimes it scrolls correctly, in others it takes a lag. In the logcat, I realized that the lag occurs when the GC kicks in.

[image: GC]

I was looking for a way to optimize my component, however I am new to Java. I read about optimizing Views, and reuse of objects width getView. Below is my current getView code:

```
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                if (null == this.parent)
                    this.parent = (ListViewOT) parent;

                if (this.parent.isInEditMode()) {
                    super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                }

                mActivity = (MainActivity) parent.getContext();
                this.c = this.getCursor();
                c.moveToPosition(position);

                if (null == convertView) {

                    view = (LinearLayout) LinearLayout.inflate(
                            this.context, R.layout.item_lvacoes, null);

                    row = (LinearLayout) view.getChildAt(1);
                    headerRow = (TableRow) this.parent.getHeader().getChildAt(0);
                    for (int j = 0; j < this.c.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                        columnName = c.getColumnName(j);

                        if (columnName.startsWith("Status")) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        headerCell = (CelulasLV) headerRow.getChildAt(j);
                        current_width = headerCell.getWidth();
                        headerCell.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                        cell_width = AdapterLVAcoes.CalculateTextSize(headerCell.getPaint(), c.getColumnName(j));
                        column_width = this.parent.getColumnWidthAt(j);

                        if (column_width == 0)
                            headerCell.setWidth(0);
                        else if (cell_width <= column_width)
                        {
                            if (current_width != column_width)
                                headerCell.setWidth(column_width);
                        } else
                        {
                            this.changedWidth = true;
                            this.parent.setColumnWidthAt(j, cell_width);
                        }

                        column = new CelulasLV(this.context,(ListViewOT) parent);
                        if (columnName.equals("No"))
                            column.setText("" + (position + 1));
                        else
                            column.setText(c.getString(j));

                        column.setIndexColumn(j);
                        column.setIndexRow(position);
                        column.setEPC(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));

                        int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Status"));
                        if (status == 0)
                            column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell));
                        else if (status == 1)
                            column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellachado));
                        else if (status == 2)
                            column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellextraviado));
                        else if (status == 3)
                            column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellinexistente));
                        else if (status == 4)
                            column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellpreachado));

                        activity.registerForContextMenu(column);
                        cell_width = AdapterLVAcoes.CalculateTextSize(column.getPaint(), column.getText().toString());
                        column_width = this.parent.getColumnWidthAt(j);

                        if (column_width == 0)
                            column.setWidth(0);
                        else if (cell_width <= column_width)
                            column.setWidth(column_width);
                        else
                        {
                            this.changedWidth = true;
                            this.parent.setColumnWidthAt(j, cell_width);
                        }
                        row.addView(column);
                    }
                    return view;
                }
                else 
                {
                    view = (LinearLayout) convertView;
                    row = (LinearLayout) view.getChildAt(1);
                    int i = 0;
                    headerRow = (TableRow) this.parent.getHeader().getChildAt(0);
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < this.c.getColumnCount(); j++)
                        {
                            columnName = c.getColumnName(j);

                            if (columnName.startsWith("Status")) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            headerCell = (CelulasLV) headerRow.getChildAt(j);
                            current_width = headerCell.getWidth();
                            headerCell.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                            cell_width = AdapterLVAcoes.CalculateTextSize(headerCell.getPaint(), c.getColumnName(j));
                            column_width = this.parent.getColumnWidthAt(j);

                            if (column_width == 0)
                                headerCell.setWidth(0);
                            else if (cell_width <= column_width)
                                if (current_width != column_width)
                                    headerCell.setWidth(column_width);
                            else
                            {
                                this.changedWidth = true;
                                this.parent.setColumnWidthAt(j, cell_width);
                            }
                            column = (CelulasLV) row.getChildAt(i);

                            if (columnName.equals("No"))
                                column.setText("" + (position + 1));
                            else
                                column.setText(c.getString(j));

                            column.setIndexColumn(j);
                            column.setIndexRow(position);
                            column.setRealIndex(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("No")));
                            column.setEPC(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));

                            status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Status"));
                            if (status == 0)
                                column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell));
                            else if (status == 1)
                                column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellachado));
                            else if (status == 2)
                                column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellextraviado));
                            else if (status == 3)
                                column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellinexistente));
                            else if (status == 4)
                                column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellpreachado));

                            activity.registerForContextMenu(column);
                            column.setOnClickListener(this.cellClick);
                            cell_width = AdapterLVAcoes.CalculateTextSize(column.getPaint(), column.getText().toString());
                            column_width = this.parent.getColumnWidthAt(j);

                            if (column_width == 0)
                                column.setWidth(0);
                            else if (cell_width <= column_width)
                                column.setWidth(column_width);
                            else 
                            {
                                this.changedWidth = true;
                                this.parent.setColumnWidthAt(j, cell_width);
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    return convertView;
                }
            }
```

It basically redraws the columns according to the widest column found.

How to optimize my component, so these lags do not occur when the GC into action?

Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english.

Comment: (1) Why can't you use a `ListView` for this? (2) I don't think the GC is slowing you down I think the use of a scrolling table view is. If you can use a `ListView` or some other optimized structure that recycles views it will likely be much smoother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, I'm cringing just looking at this and your other post.  Lets try to work with what you have. You have some pretty complicated algorithms in determining width but before we address that, we can definitely speed things up.  I will paint a higher overview of what you should do. You'll have to translate that into the code as this is a complex problem.

You'll need to create a cache which given a position and a column # will store the measured width. Always check your cache first and only measure if there's nothing found.  The `getView()` method can be invoked 3-4 times per position.  So this should yield a huge improvement.

An alternative to this, if you have a lot of dynamic text or repetitive text...you can create a cache based on text instead.  So for a given String, you cache what the measured width is.

Assuming you are only ever showing text in the columns, there's an alternative measuring solution which may be quicker. Just use the TextView's `getPaint().measureText(String)` method.  It'll return the width of the text in pixels.  You'll probably need to throw on some fluff like an additional 4-8 dp but that may be quicker then what you are doing.

**Cache Example:**

In the constructor of the adapter, do something like:

```
Map<String, Float> mWidthCache = new HashMap<String, Float>();
```

Then within the for loop within `getView()` do something like:

```
String key = String.valueOf(position) + c.getColumnName(j);
Float measuredWidth = mWidthCache.get(key);
if (width == null) {
    //Calculate measuredWidth
    mWidthCache.put(key, measuredWidth); //Then place back in cache
}

//Adjust width of layout based on measureWidth
```

Comment: Hello Jay. I have no idea how to cache the position. Can you help me a little bit more?

Comment: Updated with simple cache example

Comment: OK. This solution seems to be correct. But I am not able to implement it. As I said before, I'm new to Android, and the function shown is much more complex than your example. But thank you anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I believe GC kicks in a lot because you're churning through too much memory.

Instead of recreating your bitmaps every time you call `getView (...)` you need to cache them - create them once and store them in memory, then just reuse them instead of reloading them.

Create new function:

```
private Drawable getMyBackgroundDrawable (int status)
{    
    if (status == 0)
        return a;
    else if (status == 1)
        return b;
    else if (status == 2)
        return c;
    else if (status == 3)
        return d;
    else if (status == 4)
        return e;
    return null;
}
```

You'll need to define the cached drawables in your class body:

```
Drawable a;
Drawable b;
Drawable c;
Drawable d;
Drawable e;
```

And somewhere in this class load the drawables (in the constructor or in `onFinishInflate` is usually my choice):

```
a = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell);
b = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellachado);
c = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellextraviado);
d = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellinexistente);
e = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellpreachado);
```

Remove these (you have them twice):

```
if (status == 0)
    column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell));
else if (status == 1)
    column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellachado));
else if (status == 2)
    column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellextraviado));
else if (status == 3)
    column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellinexistente));
else if (status == 4)
   column.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cellpreachado));
```

Replace them with:

```
column.setBackgroundDrawable(getMyBackgroundDrawable (status));
```

Please note that I haven't compiled or tested any of this code, so you may need to fix some syntax errors I missed.

Comment: Hello Kibler88. Thank you for the help. I did what you recommended, but the result still the same. Is there anything else I can do?