# Android custom component - How to automatically fix the width of columns

Tags: android, listview, gridview, garbage-collection, adapter

I created a custom component called ScrollListView, which is basically a table, extending ListView. Using the function getView below, I fill this component with the data coming from the database. It works perfectly and the result is visually that:

[image: result]

Obviously I would like the cells were aligned, like this:

[image: cells aligned]

To achieve this, currently I perform the calculations to measure all the cell sizes, and then adjust the column based on the widest cell, but GC is called several times, causing lag during scrolling, as previously reported [is this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789902/gc-lagging-app-when-scrolling-my-custom-component)

My question is: how to automatically fix/measure the size of the columns, without crazy calculations called in every getView call, extinguishing all those GC occurrences? I've tried to extend the GridView instead ListView, but it did not work. I´m new on Android.

**(I CAN NOT use a standard component, such as GridView or GridLayout, I MUST use my custom component ScrollListView due to other more complex functions that currently operate correctly)**

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Edit: Here is my code (the getView code is in the thread already mentioned):

scroll_listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/BackGroundColor"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <android.ListView
             android:id="@+id/rows_lv"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_margin="0dip"
             android:divider="@null"
             android:dividerHeight="0dp"
             android:padding="0dip"
             android:scrollbars="horizontal"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:stretchColumns="*"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And my ScrollListView.java

```
  public class ScrollListView extends LinearLayout
{

    TableLayout header;
    ListView rows;
    public ScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.scroll_listview,this);

        if (!this.isInEditMode())
        {
            rows = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.rows_lv);
            header = (TableLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.header_lv);
            rows.setOnRedrawListener(new OnListViewRedraw() {


                @Override
                public void onBeforeRedraw() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAfterRedraw() {
                }

            });
            rows.setHeader(header);
            rows.setMyParent(this);
        }

    // (and so on...)
```

Comment: Can you post your xml file corresponding to the inflated view on each row of Listview  plz ?

Comment: Hello Maxouille, I updated my question

Comment: I'm gonna post my answer on your other posting as it relates more to how to improve your performance in the getView method

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`TableLayout.onMeasure()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/widget/TableLayout.java#TableLayout.onMeasure%28int%2Cint%29) source code. They find the widths of the cells for all children, then adjusts all children to match accordingly. You will need some modified version of this to fit your needs.